# Postgres: Unable to determine percent of successful events ending in a completed trip

Tags: sql, postgresql

SQL Gurus, 
I'm trying to solve this challenging problem as I'm practicing my SQL skills, however I'm stuck and would appreciate if someone could help.

A signup is defined as an event labelled ‘sign_up_success’ within the events table. For each city (‘A’ and ‘B’) and each day of the week, determine the percentage of signups in the first week of 2016 that resulted in completed a trip within 10 hours of the sign up date.

Table Name: trips

```
Column Name                           Datatype
id                                     integer
client_id                              integer (Foreign keyed to 
events.rider_id)
driver_id                              integer
city_id                                Integer (Foreign keyed to 
cities.city_id)
client_rating                          integer
driver_rating                          integer
request_at                             Timestamp with timezone
predicted_eta                          Integer
actual_eta                             Integer
status                                 Enum(‘completed’, 
‘cancelled_by_driver’, ‘cancelled_by_client’)
```

Table Name: cities

```
Column Name   Datatype
city_id        integer
city_name      string
```

Table Name: events

```
Column Name     Datatype
device_id        integer
rider_id         integer
city_id          integer
event_name       Enum(‘sign_up_success’, ‘attempted_sign_up’, 
‘sign_up_failure’)
_ts              Timestamp with timezone
```

Tried something on this lines, however its no where near the expected answer:

```
SELECT *
FROM trips AS trips
LEFT JOIN cities AS cities ON trips.city_id = cities.city_id
LEFT JOIN events AS events ON events.client_id = events.rider_id
WHERE events.event_name = "sign_up_success"
AND Convert(datetime, trips.request_at') <= Convert(datetime, '2016-01-
07' )
AND DATEDIFF(d, Convert(datetime, events._ts), Convert(datetime, 
trips.request_at)) < 7 days
AND events.status = "completed
```

Desired Results look like below:

```
Monday  A   x%
Monday  B   y%
Tuesday  A   z% 
Tuesday  A   p%
```

Can someone please help.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I assume that "trips"."city_id" is mandatory, so I use INNER JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN when joining with cities.

Then, to specify string constants, you need to use single quotes.
There are some other changes in the query -- hope you'll notice them yourself.

Also, the query might fail, since I didn't run it actually (you didn't provide boilerplate SQL unfortunately).

date_trunc() function with 'week' first parameter converts your timestamp to "first day of the corresponding week, time 00:00:00", based on your current timezone settings (see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html).

I used GROUP BY on that value and second "layer" of grouping was city ID.

Also, I used "filter (where ...)" next to count() -- it allows to count only desired rows.

Finally, I used CTE to improve the query's structure and readability.

Let me know if it fails, I'll fix it. In general, this approach must work.

```
with data as (
  select
    left(date_trunc('week', t.request_at)::text, 10) as period,
    c.city_id,
    count(distinct t.id) as trips_count,
    count(*) filter (
      where
        e.event_name = 'sign_up_success'
        and e._ts < t.request_at + interval '10 hour'
    ) as successes_count
  from trips as t
  join cities as c on t.city_id = c.city_id
  left join events as e on t.client_id = e.rider_id and e._ts
  where
    t.request_at between '2016-01-01' and '2016-01-08'
  group by 1, 2
)
select
  *,
  round(100 * success_count::numeric / trips_count, 2)::text || '%' as ratio_percent
from data
order by period, city_id
;
```

Comment: Upvoted, because `count(*) filter (WHERE ...)` is very interesting! It also looks good. But i think he wants `successful within 10 hours`, so it may be `requested_at + interval '10 hours'`. Oh, and the lower bound for the first week timestamp would likely be `2016-01-01`, which i don't see in your query, yet. (There could be data before that point in time). But those things are mere details.

Comment: By the way, why do you use `distinct t.id`? Can duplicates on `t.id` happen? If so, would removing duplicates affect the percentage calculated? Should either both be with `DISTINCT` or none at all?

Comment: I thought that per each trip, multiple events can happen.

Comment: Thanks @Nick for this amazing work. It would take some time for me to digest the info. Unfortunately, I only have the schema, and no data. But, I'm hopeful that it would work.